# Batch file to count number of hops and run FTP based on the results

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I need to create a batch job(.bat) file to run FTP copy to my server, however this must only run if the server is reachable by 1 hop via "tracert" (or any other command) to prevent the jobs from running when the users are logged into the VPN from a remote location.

I can run the trace, but I am not sure on how to use the results to limit the FTP part from running if it hops more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedExpansion
set hops=0
FOR /F "tokens=1,8,9 delims= " %%A IN ('Tracert -h 2 127.0.0.1') do (
set /a test=%%A*1
if !test! geq 1 set /a hops=!hops!+1
)
if %hops% lss 2 echo run ftp-command here
```

this checks if amount of hops needed is 1 and executes a command if it's true.
You still need to change the 127.0.0.1 to your IP and put your command where the echo is.